# 2 argument in if - when isset button or onload

Tags: php, if-statement, onload, isset

I have argument which "do something" when i press the `searchbutton`, but I want to do the same on load webpage

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST['searchbutton'])) {
$time = time();
$time_now = (date("H:i:s",$time));
echo $time_now;
}
?>
```

I want to do this when page is loading and after click button `searchbutton`

Is there any options to use two arguments in this if like this:

```
if ((window.onload) OR (isset($_POST['searchbutton'])))
```

Comment: `window.onload` is in the client, not the server.

Comment: If you want to do the same thing in the initial page and when they submit the form, it doesn't need to be inside the `if`.

Comment: Yeah, it could be outside if and it show well, but after click button the output is duplicated, this is the biggest problem with duplicated output

Comment: Why would anything be duplicated? When you submit the search form, it reloads the page and just shows it once outside the `if`.